# Problem with login logic and json web token use in react app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to use jsonwebtokens and jwtdecode in my login logic for a portfolio project im working on as a newer coder and i cant figure out whats wrong. I used console logs to find out that its something in my try catch block in my login logic but at this point i dont know if its my authorization utils that arent working or if this just isnt going to work for my password encryption. Any help would be appreciated!

https://github.com/clarissafuller/flipping-app

I've tried seeding user data and logging in and it keeps giving me invalid username and password even though i know theyre right. I've tried changing my auth files both on server and client side and i've read through the documentation for the npm packages